# Broadcast is not reaching the receiver method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am doing a sample alarm app.

After setting the time, broadcast is set but the receiver method is not get called at the time

ReminderMainActivity:

```
public class ReminderMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener                                                 {

    DatePicker          _datePicker         = null;
    TimePicker          _timePicker         = null;
    EditText            _taskEditText       = null;
    Button              _setButton          = null;
    String              _st_time            = null;
    String              _st_date            = null;
    Calendar            _calendar           = null;
    Calendar            _calendarNow        = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_view);
        init();
    }


    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _datePicker   = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        _timePicker   = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
        _taskEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_desc);
        _setButton    = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_button);
         _calendarNow  = Calendar.getInstance();
        _calendar = (Calendar) _calendarNow.clone();

        _timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        _setButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String st_taskDescription = _taskEditText.getText().toString();
        int year = _datePicker.getYear();
        int monthOfYear = _datePicker.getMonth();
        int dayOfMonth = _datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


        _calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        _calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        _calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        _calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        _calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Log.i("", "Alarm Set:  " + _calendar.getTimeInMillis());
         if(_calendar.compareTo(_calendarNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                _calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                Log.i("", "Time passed : " + _calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Time passed" + _calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }



        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderMainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);        
        alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set:  " + _calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        _calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        _st_time = hourOfDay + " : " + minute;
    }

}
```

Receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("AlarmActivity", "Receiver");
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Intent Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

If I replace `_calendar.getTimeInMillis()` with
`System.CurrentTimeInMillis()` then it works..but that's not what I want

Receiver class is mentioned in manifest also.
I am not able to find the mistake. Can anyone help? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Your `_calendar` may be in the past, depending on the values that you use with `set()`. Beyond that, use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to examine your scheduled alarm.

Comment: I didnt understandt.how to use that 2nd one?can you make it clear

Comment: Open up a command prompt, and type in **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`**. If **`adb`** is in your path, this will dump system information related to alarms from your device or emulator. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#othershellcommands

Comment: if i replace _calendar.getTimeInMillis() with System.CurrentTimeInMillis() then it works..but thats not what i want.

Comment: Then figure out where you are going wrong in creating your `_calendar`. For example, you are not setting the hour. And, as I noted, you may be setting a date that is in the past.

Comment: i tried printing the date in logcat.it shows the date and time i selected.

Comment: month value was added by 1 that made it wrong .Also after clearing calender got correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution.after getting instance of calender ,clear the values.

```
_calendarNow  = Calendar.getInstance();
_calendar = (Calendar) _calendarNow.clone();
_calendar.clear();
```